# Dynamic div to center the middle of text

Tags: css, html, alignment, center, text-alignment

I have found several questions on stackoverflow that relate to this issue, but mine is a little unique and I have not been able to figure out a solution. I'm also not a css expert, go figure.

My situation is as follows: I have a string inside a div that must be displayed with the following constraints:

Using the following string as an example:
"The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dogs, again and again."

1. The middle of the text must be aligned in the middle of the div.
2. Div can be 100% wide, but must be restricted to one line. If the window is too small, truncation of text should happen on either side but the center of the text must always be visible. For example, if the window is too small, the div contents may be: "over the", with the rest being truncated on either side, and so on.

What css can help me achieve this? I have tried the following to no avail:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type='text/css' >
    div {
        width:100%;
        border:solid 1px black;
        text-align: center;
        vertical-align:middle;
        display: table-cell;
        white-space:nowrap;
        overflow:hidden;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dogs, again and again as well too.
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The motivation here is that I am trying to create a mobile web app that will show some search results in a list. The search text will always be highligted, and I want to make sure it is always visible in the list. So if the search query was "lazy dogs", I cannot fit the entire search result in one line, so I'll need to fit it in a div that is 100% wide with "lazy dogs" shown in the middle, with excess text truncated on either side.

So the user might see something like this as one of the results in the list. (The "..." are not necessary, shown here for clarification):

... the **lazy dogs**, again...

Furthermore, when user switches the device orientation between landscape and portrait, the list item should gracefully exand and show more text.

I am sure there is an elegant css way to do this, instead of messy javascript route that I am now contemplating.

Please let me know if I can provide any clarifications or if there is an alternative way of achieving what I am trying to do. Or perhaps this is not a good UI design choice to begin with?

As always, any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Mohammad

Comment: [This link](https://coderwall.com/p/oo2bqg) might be of interest

Comment: Even in your example, the words "lazy dogs" are not in the middle of the line. You really want the result to center on these words. Really, this is not a job for CSS. It's more of a programming issue. And TBH, I'm not keen on the idea of text being hidden and inaccessible.

Answer (score 2):

```
div {
    margin:0 -50% 0 -50%;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    position:relative;
    left: 50%;
}
span {
    width: 100%;
 overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
    margin: 0 -50%;
 white-space:nowrap;

}
```

With the following html:

```
<div>
<span>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dogs, again and again as well too.</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `#id-of-div { width: auto; } body { text-align: center; overflow-x: hidden; }`
I'm not *exactly* sure what you mean, or if it'll work, but try it anyway.